# count the number of times a cell has dependents in excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

In the picture, you see I have 3 columns.

I have written the VBA code to show the count of dependents in C column.
Here is code.

`sub countdep()
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Dependents.Count
end sub`

But the problem is in `C4` the result of count is 1 but actually I have linked the `B4` 3 times in A4. I want the result 3 in cell `C4`.

I want to count the number of times a cell is dependent rather than the count of the dependent cells.

Thanks for your time...

[image]

Comment: Dependents only counts the number of formula dependents not each time the cell is referenced.  BTW I get 2 in C4 based on B4 which is correct as there are two formula dependent on it

Comment: so is there any other way to count the number of times the cell is referenced?

Comment: You would need to create your own procedure and go through all the dependents and count how many time that address is found in the ranges in the formula.  It will be very intensive to capture all variants of the range.